# Identifying Retrofit 2 requests

Tags: java, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

Sometimes requests fail, and in case it's not due to client error (i.e.: not 4xx) then I'd like to retry to send the same request.
All my requests have a request id header, and when I send a certain request again (retry) I need to send the same id as the one used in the first place.

This sounds like a simple thing, but it turns out to be quite hard to accomplish with Retrofit 2, unless of course I'm missing something.

All of my requests are async, and so in the callback, in case I need to retry I'm doing this:

```
public void onResponse(final Call<T> call, final Response<T> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        handleResponse(response);
    } else if (response.code() >= 400 && response.code() < 500) {
        handleClientError(response);
    } else {
        call.clone().enqueue(this);
    }
}
```

I also have an interceptor for adding headers to all requests:

```
new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        final Request request = chain.request();

        final Request.Builder newRequestBuilder = request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Header1-name", "Header1-value")
                .addHeader("Header2-name", "Header2-value")
                ...
                .addHeader("HeaderN-name", "HeaderN-value");

        if (request.header("REQUEST-ID") == null) {
            newRequestBuilder.addHeader("REQUEST-ID", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }

        return chain.proceed(newRequestBuilder.build());
    }
};
```

I thought that since I'm cloning the `Call` then the (retry) request will have the headers of the previous one but that's not the case (probably because the `Call` is cloned and not the `Request`).

My problem is that I have no way of identifying the request or call in my `Interceptor.intercept` so I can't maintain a map of request/calls to id.
There's also no way of adding info to the calls/requests (as they are not generated by me and lack and setters for such a case).

I thought that maybe I can use the `Request.tag` method but again, I have no control of the object instance that is assigned there and the objects are different between requests.
And if we're already on this subject, what is this tag anyway? I can't find documentation about it.

Any idea how I can somehow pull this off?
Thanks

Comment: hey did u find out what that tag object is on the request

Comment: @AmanSatija Nope, but I haven't looked more into this after coming up with the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took another approach to this, instead of using network interceptors and callbacks, I wrote a solution which uses a network interceptor:

```
class BackoffRetryInteceptor implements Interceptor {
    private static final long RETRY_INITIAL_DELAY = 500;
    private static final long RETRY_MAX_DELAY = 35000;

    @Override
    public Response intercept(final Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        final Headers.Builder headersBuilder = new Headers.Builder();
        addHeaders(headersBuilder);

        final Headers headers = headersBuilder.build();
        long delay = RETRY_INITIAL_DELAY;
        Response response = null;
        IOException exception = null;

        while (delay < RETRY_MAX_DELAY) {
            exception = null;
            request = request.newBuilder().headers(headers).build();

            try {
                response = chain.proceed(request);

                if (response.isSuccessful() || response.code() != 500) {
                    return response;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                exception = e;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
                delay *= 2;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                delay = RETRY_MAX_DELAY;
            }
        }

        if (exception != null) {
            throw exception;
        }

        return response;
    }

    private static void addHeaders(final Headers.Builder headers) {
        headers.add("Header1-name", "Header1-value")
                .add("Header2-name", "Header2-value")
                ...
                .add("HeaderN-name", "HeaderN-value")
                .add("Request-Id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }
}
```

This seems to work well in my tests.
The main problem though is the blocking of the network threads.

If anyone can think up a better solution I'd love to hear it.